# Where Does Audiosurf Put Corkscrews?

Tags: audiosurf

Color shifts and track steepness are determined by the intensity of the song.  However, I find that corkscrews are placed seemingly randomly.  What determines their placement?

EDIT: Adding a bounty because the only two answers are a bit lacking in evidence.

Comment: What do you mean by corkscrews?

Comment: @Raven See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coArJdvlOc0.

Comment: Whoa. I've never seen those before. Must be a more recent addition than what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Raven They've been around for as long as I can remember.  That video is from 2008.

Comment: Then perhaps my library has just been absent them. 2008 is about when I was last playing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing for a while, I'm now under the impression that corkscrews are in fact placed completely randomly in the song.  Unlike other people who seem to only encounter them at intense moments of songs, I may have actually encountered MORE of them in the *least* intense moments of songs (intro, outro), in addition to some others which seemed arbitrarily placed throughout tracks.

However, given that on any given track, the corkscrews will always be in the same place, there **must** be some sort of operation going on that determines their placement, but I'll be damned if I have a clue what it is.

---

Anyway, this was too long for a comment.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer and awarding the bounty because it's the most "real" answer.  As much as I'd like to believe that corkscrews usually show up in fast/intense songs, that's obviously not the case.

Comment: @Maxpm > If I discover anything else about them while playing, I'll make sure to append it here.

Answer (score 2):

All I can say is that I have never seen them on easier difficulties but they sometimes show up on harder difficulty levels in fast/intense tracks.

They really should make these more common since they are really cool ^^

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, they seem to show up on steep downhill sections of songs. They are more likely to show up in Ironmode.

(update) Although they are more likely to show up on more difficult sections, GnomeSlice pointed out in the comments that a corkscrew showed up *right at the end of a song, when it was fading out. Strictly purple section.*

Comment: The question is not why, but "where". Please revise your answer.

Comment: @Bora: Revised. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder, but I just had one appear right at the end of a song, when it was fading out.  Strictly purple section.  :S